# Can I replace the icon in the uk-offcanvas-close, uk-close to chevron-right?

Tags: javascript, getuikit

[getuikit](https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas) Version 3.1.5, without jquery dependency

I would like to change the "x" icon for some uk-offcanvas-close to ">" instead:
if ".closedetail> button", then icon is "chevron-right" (>) instead of "close" (X)

```
<div class="closedetail">
    <button class="uk-offcanvas-close" type="button" uk-close></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best answer, but you can use `uk-toggle` instead of `uk-offcanvas-close`. The toggle is used the same way as in button that opens the offcanvas - and because it's a toggle, it closes the offcanvas when it's open already. By replacing this, you're then able to set whatever icon you want

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.5/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.5/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.5/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-small-right" type="button" uk-toggle="target: #offcanvas-usage">Open</button>

<div id="offcanvas-usage" uk-offcanvas>
    <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">

        <!-- Instead of using uk-offcanvas-close, we can use uk-toggle -->
        <button type="button" class="uk-align-right" uk-toggle="target: #offcanvas-usage" uk-icon="chevron-right"></button>

        <h3>Title</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the support. There is certainly a javascript solution, or css ... I will use your solution for the time being. Greetings, Cem

Comment: Icons are inserted by JS, so using CSS is not impossible but not very effective. Also replacing the icon with JS can be possible, but you'd be doing it twice (first it loads close icon, then replace with chevron). As JS loads SVG there, I think this is more effective solution

Comment: thanks. i am well versed with css and svg but i am a beginner in things javascript (uikit, without jquery dependency). is there an example of how to do this with javascript (UIkit.offcanvas () ...;)?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by this way

```js
$(".closedetail > button").html("<i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="closedetail">
    <button class="uk-offcanvas-close" type="button" uk-close></button>
</div>
```

Comment: he wants an icon, not a generic text arrow

Comment: still, *without jquery dependency* and uikit has its own set of icons, why would he load FontAwesome??